# no spacing in column headers (oracle reports 10g compiled on linux)

Tags: linux, oracle10g, newline

I'm having difficulty with formatting in the column header of Oracle reports.

Sometimes I have column headings, which have names which must span more than one line.

For example, I have a heading called "Remaining Days" in one of my reports. In the Oracle Reports Builder 10g It appears as:

```
Remaining
Days
```

[image]

i.e. there is a newline between "Remaining" and "Days"

The output appears properly when I generate the report from the report builder, however, when I compile the report on the server, then run it, the results are as follows:

```
RemainingDa
ys
```

[image]
Is there a way to force a newline in this column name?

Comment: Thanks Ben, I was trying to find the tags page, but apparently I'm blind today. :)

Comment: Just checking - are you *sure* there is a newline between the `g` and the `D`? Maybe the width of the item in Reports Builder causes it to wrap it at that point, but the effect of font changes on the server allows two extra characters to fit. Try making the item wider, see if it wraps at a different point.

Comment: Yeah.  There is a newline there for sure.  What was suggested to me was that I simply split the two words into two different text boxes.  That seems like a fair bit of a task when I'll have to change 10 reports using that method, hence why I'm looking for a way to force the newline.  
I posted some pictures (grainy, sorry!), and it would appear that if there's a newline character, it gets trimmed in compilation, but it seems that spaces still work.

Comment: Agreed, it looks like an issue with the character used for the newline. What happens if you remove the newlines and add them in again (i.e. edit the field, and press Enter to put the newline back in)?

Comment: When I remove them, then replace them nothing changes after compilation.  It ends up squeezing it all onto the same line.

Comment: Hmm. In that case I don't know, sorry. A workaround would be to separate them into two boilerplate items.

Comment: No worries, thanks for the effort!